# lambda custom aggregate function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, lambda

I am working with a dataset that looks like the one below (values changed and the real one is a lot larger)

```
fruit_type, temp, count
apple, 12, 4
apple, 14, 6
pear, 12, 6
pear, 16, 2
grape 12, 5
peach, 9, 33
peach 6, 3
```

I am trying to utilize a numpy agg function to find the percent of the total count each of the counts are for each temp. I also would like a column to represent the total count. Below is the code that I have been trying.

```
data3 = data2.groupby('fruit_type')['count'].agg({
    'prob' : lambda count: ((count) / count.sum()),
    'total' : lambda count: count.size
    })
```

The temp values are discrete. I would like count to be aggregated on a row by row basis where the total count sum is grouped by the fruit type. Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the first `lambda count: count/count.sum()`. It returns the same shape as the group rather than aggregating it to a scalar.

You might want to do a `transform` instead of `agg`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# suppose this is your df
df

Out[83]: 
  fruit_type   temp   count
0      apple     12       4
1      apple     14       6
2       pear     12       6
3       pear     16       2
4      grape     12       5
5      peach      9      33
6      peach      6       3


# prob part
df['prob'] = df.groupby('fruit_type')['count'].transform(lambda count: ((count) / count.sum()))

# total part
df['total_count'] = df.groupby('fruit_type')['count'].transform(lambda count: count.sum())

df

Out[87]: 
  fruit_type  temp  count    prob  total_count
0      apple    12      4  0.4000           10
1      apple    14      6  0.6000           10
2       pear    12      6  0.7500            8
3       pear    16      2  0.2500            8
4      grape    12      5  1.0000            5
5      peach     9     33  0.9167           36
6      peach     6      3  0.0833           36
```

Comment: How can I make it aggregate the larger scalar?

Comment: @user3609179 I've added some code to illustrate how to use `transform`. Also, is there a particular reason that why you want `size` in `'total' : lambda count: count.size` instead of `.sum()`

Comment: I want the aggregate total by fruit. Does that work in the current snippet you posted?